# Calendars in WinRT

Tags: calendar, windows-runtime

I'm porting my library to WinRT and it relies on System.Globalization.Calendar class and its derived classes, like GregorianCalendar and HijriCalendar, etc. Although these classes are all there in Silverlight/WPF I can only find the base Calendar class in WinRT. I have tried both System.Globalization and Windows.Globalization namespaces and both seem to have shrunk in WinRT version.

Is derived calendars removed altogether from WinRT and how we should get culture specific calendars?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, derived calendars are removed from WinRT.
But all(or may be most) functionality is available through Windows.Globalisation.Calendar.
It includes conversion of dates between different types of calendars, date string representation etc.